# Frontend get form fields as array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have html form with several inputs with same name, I want to get all values from fields with javascripts as array.

```
<form id="myForm">
    <table class="table"> 
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Val 1</th>
                <th>Val 2</th>
                <th>Val 3</th>
                <th>Val 4</th>
                <th>Val 5</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="val_1" value="someVal"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="val_2" value="someVal"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="val_3" value="someVal"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="val_4" value="someVal"></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="val_5">
                        <option value="1">One</option>
                        <option value="2">Tow</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    <table>
</form>
```

Form table has more than 20 tr with same fields, I try with jquery serialize and serializeArray.. but return value not like what I want.

I want the result to be return as:

```
[
0: {val: "value", val:"value"},
1: {val: "value", val:"value"}
and ......
]
```

***Update:***
Yes I can change name attr to start loop from 1 to 100 ex: val_1 start val_100 end Or if anyone have other idea please share, I don't want return value to be process via PHP / jquery ajax .. but I want the result to be return as:

```
[
  0: {val_0: "text:, val_1: "text", val_2: "text", val_3: "text", val_4: "text"},
1: {val_5: "text:, val_6: "text", val_7: "text", val_8: "text", val_9: "text"},
2: {val_10: "text:, val_11: "text", val_12: "text", val_13: "text", val_14: "text"},
3: {val_15: "text:, val_16: "text", val_17: "text", val_18: "text", val_19: "text"},

and so on ....
]
```

by this way I can process result to database without and backend process

Comment: If you're trying to send the form to backend service, you can use `FormData`

Comment: The result you want is not practical; each element of the array, each object should have unique keys rather than all being `val`.

Comment: multiple inputs with the same `name attributes`?

Comment: @KarlL Yes i mean name attr

Comment: Where is _your_ attempt to try and implement this? You should always show one, this is not a code-writing service!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AFTER UPDATE**

After the update of your question I think you have to make an own script for getting the form data in this specific format. You could iterate the form elements and get the index through the position of the parents row like that:

```js
var $element, name, rowIndex,
  $formElements = $('#myForm').find('input, select, textarea'),
  result = [];

for (var element of $formElements) {
  $element = $(element);

  rowIndex = $element.closest('tr').index();
  name = $element.attr('name').replace('[', '').replace(']', '');

  if (typeof result[rowIndex] == 'undefined') {
    result[rowIndex] = {};
  }

  result[rowIndex][name] = $element.val();
}

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Val 1</th>
        <th>Val 2</th>
        <th>Val 3</th>
        <th>Val 4</th>
        <th>Val 5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="val_0[]" value="someVal 00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="val_1[]" value="someVal 01"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="val_2[]" value="someVal 02"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="val_3[]" value="someVal 03"></td>
        <td>
          <select name="val_4[]">
            <option value="01">One</option>
            <option value="02">Tow</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="val_0[]" value="someVal 10"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="val_1[]" value="someVal 11"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="val_2[]" value="someVal 12"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="val_3[]" value="someVal 13"></td>
        <td>
          <select name="val_4[]">
            <option value="11">One</option>
            <option value="12">Tow</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

**ORIGINAL**

First you can't create objects with duplicate attributes, every attribute has to get unique name.
But you can simply use arrays in the name attributes of your input elements. Then you can serialize the elements and put it in for example into a ajax request.

```js
var $myForm = $('#myForm'),
  serialized = $myForm.serialize();

// replaces are just used for showing
console.log(
  serialized.replace(new RegExp('%5B', 'g'), '[').replace(new RegExp('%5D', 'g'), ']')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Val 1</th>
        <th>Val 2</th>
        <th>Val 3</th>
        <th>Val 4</th>
        <th>Val 5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="val_1[]" value="someVal"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="val_2[]" value="someVal"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="val_3[]" value="someVal"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="val_4[]" value="someVal"></td>
        <td>
          <select name="val_5[]">
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Tow</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="val_1[]" value="someVal"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="val_2[]" value="someVal"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="val_3[]" value="someVal"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="val_4[]" value="someVal"></td>
        <td>
          <select name="val_5[]">
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Tow</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

The example above should produce this result in PHP:

```php
array(5) {
  ["val_1"]=> array(2) {
    [0]=> string(7) "someVal"
    [1]=> string(7) "someVal"
  }
  ["val_2"]=> array(2) {
    [0]=> string(7) "someVal"
    [1]=> string(7) "someVal"
  }
  ["val_3"]=> array(2) {
    [0]=> string(7) "someVal"
    [1]=> string(7) "someVal"
  }
  ["val_4"]=> array(2) {
    [0]=> string(7) "someVal"
    [1]=> string(7) "someVal"
  }
  ["val_5"]=> array(2) {
    [0]=> string(1) "1"
    [1]=> string(1) "1"
  }
}
```

Another Possibility: But if you need to get the described result in jQuery you have to code something like that:

```js
var element, index,
  $myForm = $('#myForm'),
  serialized = $myForm.serializeArray(),
  serializedLength = serialized.length,
  finalResult = [];

for (var i = 0; i < serializedLength; i++) {
  element = serialized[i];
  index = parseInt(element.name.replace('val_', '').replace('[', '').replace(']', ''));

  if (typeof finalResult[index] == 'undefined') {
    finalResult[index] = [];
  }

  finalResult[index].push(serialized[i].value);
}

console.log(finalResult);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Val 1</th>
        <th>Val 2</th>
        <th>Val 3</th>
        <th>Val 4</th>
        <th>Val 5</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="val_0[]" value="someVal 00"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="val_1[]" value="someVal 01"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="val_2[]" value="someVal 02"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="val_3[]" value="someVal 03"></td>
        <td>
          <select name="val_4[]">
            <option value="01">One</option>
            <option value="02">Tow</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="val_0[]" value="someVal 10"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="val_1[]" value="someVal 11"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="val_2[]" value="someVal 12"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="val_3[]" value="someVal 13"></td>
        <td>
          <select name="val_4[]">
            <option value="11">One</option>
            <option value="12">Tow</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: @UfguFgullu thanks, I can do that with PHP very easy, but I'm not that good in frontend developing and process your code will return all as 10+ numbers array it mean each field is 1 array but I want result to be return 1 array with 5 values as object.

Comment: @ash First, the resulted array in PHP should be same as the `$_POST` variable looks like after submitting, it isn't a code for transforming.
And could you tell me why you need the result as an object?
As I said in my answer, you can probably use objects for this, but then you have to choose different names for the attributes, which becomes very complicated afterwards.
Please tell me, how your result should looks like, if you can't have duplicate attributes?

Comment: thanks for reply I don't need to process the result with PHP, Yes i can change name attr to loop from 1 to 100 val_1 > val_100 now it's change, the return value I want I mention in orginal question. I'm update my question again

Comment: @ash I've updated my answer, on the top you can see a possible solution.

Comment: thans for update it return error: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: @Ash In the snippet here everything is working with the given markup (no matter if the `name`s are called as array or just incremental). Maybe you have form elements without an `name` attribute?

Comment: in my case i'm loading form data dynamically form some unknown reason function get first tr as undefined, I add if condition after for loop now it's working.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a `name/value` object for each row of this form:

```
[
  {
    "val_1": "someVal0",
    "val_2": "someVal0",
    "val_3": "someVal0",
    "val_4": "someVal0",
    "val_5": "1"
  }, ....
]
```

Here is how you may do that:

```js
var values = $('.table tbody > tr').map(function() {
    var obj = {};
    $(this).find(':input').each(function() {
        obj[this.name] = this.value;
    });
    return obj;
}).get();

console.log( values );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
    <table class="table"> 
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Val 1</th>
                <th>Val 2</th>
                <th>Val 3</th>
                <th>Val 4</th>
                <th>Val 5</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="val_1" value="someVal0"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="val_2" value="someVal0"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="val_3" value="someVal0"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="val_4" value="someVal0"></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="val_5">
                        <option value="1">One</option>
                        <option value="2">Tow</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="val_1" value="someVal1"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="val_2" value="someVal1"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="val_3" value="someVal1"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="val_4" value="someVal1"></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="val_5">
                        <option value="1">One</option>
                        <option value="2">Tow</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="val_1" value="someVal2"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="val_2" value="someVal2"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="val_3" value="someVal2"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="val_4" value="someVal2"></td>
                <td>
                    <select name="val_5">
                        <option value="1">One</option>
                        <option value="2">Tow</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    <table>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you it's working what I want but I accept the first answer. :)

Comment: Very well @ash, glad you found a solution that works. Now that you have selected the right answer, feel free to upvote *all* answers that you find useful.